# How to get location accurate upto 6 meters?

Tags: android, location

I have been using `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get location in android. The issue is that it gives me an inaccurate location(accuracy ranging from 25-50) event though I have set it to `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`. It takes a very long time for the accuracy to come near to 6.

```
    locationRequest=LocationRequest.create();        
    locationRequest.setInterval(100);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    //Some other function
    locationCallback=new LocationCallback(){
        @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult){
                for(Location location:locationResult.getLocations()){
                    longitude=location.getLongitude();
                    latitude=location.getLatitude();
                    TextView txt_accuracy=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_accuracy);
                    txt_accuracy.setText("Accuracy:"+String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));
                    if(location.getAccuracy()<=6){
                        getZone();
                        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        fusedLocationProviderClient=LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback,
Looper.getMainLooper());`
```

Comment: This is likely a function of the performance of your GPS receiver, and the signals available at your location, and you cannot improve upon it by changing the API calls. Try standing in a nice, open field.

Comment: @greeble31 I have tried that. I actually started testing the app in an open field.

Comment: Still the same story. I see no reason to believe that the accuracy numbers you are getting are incorrect, or the result of some sort of misconfiguration. There are limitations to how accurate GPS is (especially in absolute terms). If the fixes you are getting are stable (that is, they don't wander too much), consider yourself fortunate.

Comment: @greeble31 Thanks. This time, I tested the app in an open field and continued requesting location updates till the accuracy got down to 6. It happened in a few seconds. I think it is just that the location takes some time to stabilize.